# throw exception on wso2

Tags: exception, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2, and would like an example to throw exception on wso2. Type I have a variable balance and wanted to validate if it is less than zero if it is to run the sequence and send a message. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways one is  `makefault` mediator , below is the syntax which you can use .

```
 <makefault version="soap11">
                <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Client"/>
                <reason value="Internal technical error. Please, contact support team"/>
                <role>WSO2</role>
                <detail expression="$ctx:FaultDetail"/>
            </makefault>
```

Other way is to call an `error sequence` which you need to define when you are building a sequence